# Alexa Skill: How to loop through an array of sound files

Tags: arrays, node.js, loops, for-loop, alexa-skills-kit

I have a skill that plays animal sounds on Amazon Alexa.

User: What does a dog sound like?
Alexa: (Bark)
User: What does a cat sound like?
Alexa: (Meow)

etc...etc.

I'm trying to add an intent that loops through the array in order and plays all the animal sound files that I have available in the array:

```
var animalNoises = {

        'bear' : {
            'noise' : "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/animals/amzn_sfx_bear_roar_small_01.mp3'/>"
        },

        'bird' : {
            'noise' : "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/animals/amzn_sfx_bird_forest_01.mp3'/>"
        },

        'cat' : {
            'noise' : "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/animals/amzn_sfx_cat_meow_1x_02.mp3'/>"
        },

        'cow' : {
            'noise' : "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/animalhouse-noises/animal+house+(cow-moo).mp3'/>"
        },

        'chicken' : {
            'noise' : "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/animals/amzn_sfx_chicken_cluck_01.mp3'/>"
        },

        'dog' : {
            'noise' : "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/animals/amzn_sfx_dog_med_bark_2x_02.mp3'/>"
        },

        'elephant' : {
            'noise' : "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/animals/amzn_sfx_elephant_01.mp3'/>"
        },

        'horse' : {
            'noise' : "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/animals/amzn_sfx_horse_whinny_01.mp3'/>"
        },

        'lion' : {
            'noise' : "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/animals/amzn_sfx_lion_roar_02.mp3'/>"
        },

        'pig' : {
            'noise' : "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/animalhouse-noises/animal+house+(pig-snort).mp3'/>"
        },

        'monkey' : {
            'noise' : "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/animals/amzn_sfx_monkey_chimp_01.mp3'/>"
        },

        'rat' : {
            'noise' : "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/animals/amzn_sfx_rat_squeak_2x_01.mp3'/>"
        },

        'raven' : {
            'noise' : "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/animals/amzn_sfx_raven_caw_2x_01.mp3'/>"
        },

        'rooster' : {
            'noise' : "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/animals/amzn_sfx_rooster_crow_02.mp3'/>"
        },

        'sheep' : {
            'noise' : "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/animals/amzn_sfx_sheep_bleat_02.mp3'/>"
        },

        'turkey' : {
            'noise' : "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/animals/amzn_sfx_turkey_gobbling_01.mp3'/>"
        },

        'wolf' : {
            'noise' : "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/ask-soundlibrary/animals/amzn_sfx_wolf_howl_02.mp3'/>"
        }

        };
```

Here is the code I have in the intent, but not having any luck getting the sound files to play:

```
 'PlayAllAnimalsIntent' : function () {
    speechOutput = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < animalNoises.length; i++) {
        var animalSounds = animalNoises[animalNoises[i]]['noise'];
        speechOutput = animalSounds;
        this.emit(":tell", speechOutput);

    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

`animalNoises.length` is `undefined` because `animalNoises` has no key `length`. Therefore `i < animalNoises.length` becomes `i < undfeined`. And since `i` first gets a value of `0`, we get `0 < undefined`.

Due to javascript's type coercion gimmicks, `0 < undefined` evaluates to `false` and the code block inside the loop is never executed.

Additionally, `var animalSounds = animalNoises[animalNoises[i]]['noise'];` will result in a TypeError, because `animalNoises[animalNoises[i]]` is `undefined`, but we never get that far.

### The fix

To iterate through an object you need an iterable representation of the object. `Object.keys(object)` will return all keys of your object as an array.

```
Object.keys(animalSounds).forEach(key => {
  const sound = animalSounds[key]['noise'];
  /* Append sound to speechOutput here */
})

this.emit(":tell", speechOutput);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it makes a lot of sense! I tried the code that you provided and for some reason it's only resulting in the first sound being played: 'bear'. I tried a few different things around your code, but didn't have any luck. I'm beginning to think that Alexa is only going to allow me to play one sound from the list. Any other ideas?

Comment: Likely ```this.emit``` is an asynchronous function and as such code execution will continue past the line that calls it before the function is finished executing. You will need to wait for it to be done executing before calling it again. You can use async-await or [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and callbacks. Consult the relevant documentation to find out what the return value of ```this.emit``` is.

Comment: Having looked at the Alexa skill documentation it seems that calling ```this.emit``` stops further execution (or at least makes subsequent emits fail). Therefore, you should build your output inside your loop and then giving the whole list to ```this.emit```. I will update my response to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks again! I actually tried building a list through a loop and sending it to `this.emit`. My console did produce every sound link as needed, but when I went to test it the Alexa Simulator, the output was only the first 5 sound files.

Again, it looks like this is a limitation of Alexa. I'm reaching out to Amazon support now to confirm this.

Comment: Amazon: 

"Thanks for reaching out to us.

Yes, there is a limit only 5 sounds can play at a time and that also should not be more than 90 seconds."